# DigitalOcean - Kubernetes - SSL - Getting 503 error only on https request

Tags: kubernetes, load, load-balancing, digital-ocean

everyone! Currently, I'm having issues with the SSL setup in one of my projects. The architecture that I'm using right now it's the following one:

- 2 to 10 auto-scalable nodes
- 10 replicas
- One load balancer

I created a let encrypt certificate and updated the Forwarding Rules of the load balancer in order to have HTTPS requests redirected to HTTP by applying the created certificate.

Unfortunately, I'm not able to access the HTTPS URL, I'm receiving a 503 (Service Unavailable) error. The HTTP request it's working fine.

Any idea of what it's happening? Thanks!